# Bind over the observableList in JavaFx

Tags: java, binding, javafx, tableview

I have a entity of some datasource. It has List of object Pojo.  It can be get by ds.getRows(). 
I'm trying to bind TableView on this list very hard.

```
tblHlp.itemsProperty().bindBidirectional(new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(ds.getRows())));
```

When I change that ObservableList  which I created FXCollections.observableArrayList(ds.getRows())) tableView is changed too. But I want to get the same effect when I change List in ds  (ds.getRows). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it like that.

What you can do is to add a ListChangeListener on the ObservableList you created and then manage manually the items to add/remove in your other list. For example something like that:

```
ListChangeListener<Object>() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged(javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Object> change) {
        while (change.next()) {
           //If items are removed
           for (Objectremitem : change.getRemoved()) {
               unfixColumn(remitem);
           }
           //If items are added
           for (Objectadditem : change.getAddedSubList()) {
               fixColumn(additem);
           }
        }
        updateHighlightSelection();
    }
};
```

Don't forget to take a look at the Javadoc here : http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html

And how to use JavaFX collections here :  http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/collections/jfxpub-collections.htm

Comment: Thank you =) It's idea. In forward direction it can be work. But what about bidirectional..

Comment: If you want it to be bi-directional, maybe wrap your other list into an ObservableList also. But beware that you do not fire your own List when you do your changes.